# JAX-RS @Path() custom format

Tags: java, regex, path, jax-rs

I'm Regex newbie. What I trying to do here is, I have **2 @PathParam** so the user can either type in **"/session"** or **"/requester"** or **anything** but these two.

If the user type "/session" or "/requester" this input will go to **pathparam 1** else the **pathparam 2**.

Here is my regex.

```
@Path("/generateotp{session:(/session[^\\w&&[^\\W]]|/requester[^\\w&&
[^\\W]])?}{senderid:(/[^/&&\\w]|(?:(?!requester|session).))?}")
```

I know I'm kind of redundant the **[^\w&&[^\W]]** part but the **[^.+]** just don works.

Extra things here. How can I cut the "/" when the input will go to the senderid pathparam. I need the user to input it in because of the *generateotp* there but when it process and throw to the pathparam, that is where i don't need it. I can use substring after that to cut it but is there anyway i can do it in the regex?

Comment: To help you build a regex, we need to know: 1) Input string, 2) exact expected output. Note that `[^\\w&&[^\\W]]` makes no sense as it matches no text (= *match `\W` but not `\W`*). `[^.+]` matches a single char that is not a `.` or `+`.

Comment: Also, see [The @Path Annotation and URI Path Templates](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp1v/index.html), there is a table showing how to provide an example that would be clearer.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? are you trying to say that you want to map /generateotp/(session or requester)/blah and have session or requester be pathparam1 and blah be pathparam2?